# /usr/bin/env: python2.6: No such file or directory error

Tags: python

I have python2.6, python2.7 and python3 in my `/usr/lib/`

I am trying to run a file which has line given below in it as its first line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

after trying to run it it gives me following error

```
/usr/bin/env: python2.6: No such file or directory
```

my default version on python is 2.7.

How I can run the file without changing the default version of python.

Comment: If you type in your terminal: `/usr/bin/env python2.6` what do you see ?

Comment: Are you sure the python executables are really under `/usr/lib` and not just the site-packages?

Comment: The [differences between python 2.6 and 2.7](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html) are nearly all compatible with older code.  You *may* be able to just change the file to refer to `python2.7`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you might be confused about the location of your python executables, versus the location of the lib site-packages.

Your python site-packages should be here:
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages

But your executables should probably be here:
/usr/bin

If you run this following command, it should tell you where it is currently finding the executables:

```
which python
which python2.7
...
```

Your $PATH environment variable should contain paths that have executable files directly underneath.
i.e.   `$ echo $PATH`
`/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/aUser/bin`

If your executable is in another location that is not in your path and you don't want to neccessarily add that location to your path, you can also just symlink it to somewhere normal....

```
ln -s /path/to/executable /usr/bin/executable
```

Here is a trick to find all the executable files named python:

```
find /usr -type f -name 'python*' -perm -a+x
```

This might help you locate python2.6

Comment: Yes your are right my python executables are in /usr/bin/. It has python and python2.7 But I want to use python2.6 without removing python2.7 as default

Comment: @bigbang: Thats fine. You need to figure out where python2.6 is located though. Can you determine where that executable lives? See my update for a find command

Comment: problem solved.. I installed python2.6. I think previously I just had site packages to python2.6

Comment: @bigbang: That would definitely fix it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need `python2.6` in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I have added /usr/lib/python2.6 and /usr/lib to $PATH but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: How do you successfully add it to the path?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create an alias to 2.7 as 2.6

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.6
```