# /bin/env: python2.7: No such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up development environment for sugar-labs project as given on http://developer.sugarlabs.org/dev-environment.md.html. I cloned the sugar-build git repository successfully. Now when I try to pull the source code giving the command `./osbuild pull` I get the following error -

```
/bin/env: python2.7: No such file or directory
```

I tried looking at a similar error in a question at [/usr/bin/env: python2.6: No such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623833/usr-bin-env-python2-6-no-such-file-or-directory-error) but couldn't follow. I am new to all this. Please help.

Edit: `/usr/bin/env` python gives Python2.7.9 and the python environment starts. `/usr/bin/env python2.7` shows no such file.

Comment: did you try `/usr/bin/env python2.7` or `/usr/bin/env python`?

Comment: yes i did. the first command shows no file. the second one gives Python2.7.9 and python environment starts.

Comment: try `which python2.7` in your terminal

Comment: `which python2.7` shows nothing. `which python` shows /c/Python27/python

Comment: Well, there are many ways to make 2.7.9 be found as 2.7, but there are also many ways to break your system. Why do you need exactly 2.7?

Comment: I believe it is because first line in the file `osbuild` contains `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a virtual environment for a project you need to install python and other packages inside the virtual environment too.

activate your virtual env and then install python inside the env

**Edit:**

You can also set the path of python interpreter when creating the virtual environment.